# Weblogic can't access admin console

Tags: weblogic

I've just added a new Authentication Provider under the realm section. This new provider is a custom LDAP server, which right now is not online, so it's not reachable. The problem is that if I try to access the weblogic console it gives me a 500 internal server error.

Message shown in the page:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

The best thing to do is start at the Home page or try the browser back button.
```

Exception:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.net.UnknownHostException: authservice.dd.aa.int
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.company.authservice.util.httpclient.protocol.bouncycastle.StandardNamesTlsSocket.connect(StandardNamesTlsSocket.java:269)
    at org.company.authservice.util.httpclient.protocol.Java5SSLSocketWrapper.connect(Java5SSLSocketWrapper.java:64)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

How can I access again the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always make a backup before manually editing the `config.xml`**

You can stop the `AdminServer`. Then edit the `config.xml` and remove the settings for the new `authentication provider` you added.

Look for the following block in the xml:

```
<sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:ldap-authenticatorType">
    ...
</sec:authentication-provider>
```

Remove this and restart the `AdminServer`.

Comment: But it's not very clear to me, why the admin console required the LDAP server up and running too. I meant to add the LDAP server only for the app I was going to deploy.

Comment: While trying to debug your configuration, make sure that the authentication control is set to 'SUFFICIENT' instead of 'REQUIRED' or left blank in the config file. Once you have everything up and running you can then change the configuration to apply your actual authentication provider.  `<sec:control-flag>SUFFICIENT</sec:control-flag>`

Comment: It was already set to OPTIONAL, then I set it to SUFFICIENT but still /console is not reachable. Can I exclude /console from being checked?